# Haproxy servers don't sync stick_table with other peers

Tags: haproxy, supervisord, systemd

I was trying to create a two peer setup sharing a stick_table (using HA-Proxy version 1.5.14 2015/07/02). Everything looked fine when I started haproxy manually (meaning simply running this):

```
/usr/sbin/haproxy-systemd-wrapper -L haproxy1 -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /run/haproxy.pid
```

When I attempted to make the whole thing run via systemd or supervisord the sync between the stick_tables seems to have stopped.
I've checked outgoing packets from each server to the other peer port (using tcpdump) and saw they don't even try to communicate
(they do listen to the peer port and frontends are accessible).

(systemd file)
**haproxy.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=HAProxy Load Balancer
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/haproxy
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/haproxy-systemd-wrapper -L haproxy1 -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /run/haproxy.pid $OPTIONS
ExecReload=/bin/kill -USR2 $MAINPID
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**haproxy.cfg (some ip addresses have been replaced with be-ip)**

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Example configuration for a possible web application.  See the
# full configuration options online.
#
#   http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt
#
#---------------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Global settings
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
global
    # to have these messages end up in /var/log/haproxy.log you will
    # need to:
    #
    # 1) configure syslog to accept network log events.  This is done
    #    by adding the '-r' option to the SYSLOGD_OPTIONS in
    #    /etc/sysconfig/syslog
    #
    # 2) configure local2 events to go to the /var/log/haproxy.log
    #   file. A line like the following can be added to
    #   /etc/sysconfig/syslog
    #
    #    local2.*                       /var/log/haproxy.log
    #
    log         127.0.0.1 local2

    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon

    # turn on stats unix socket
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# common defaults that all the 'listen' and 'backend' sections will
# use if not designated in their block
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000



#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# peers of ha-proxy cluster
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
peers mypeers enable 
        peer haproxy1 10.240.0.4:32768
        peer haproxy2 10.240.0.7:32768

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# main frontend which proxys to the backends
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
frontend  localhost 


    bind *:80
    bind *:443 ssl  crt   /etc/haproxy/ssl/a/real.pem 
    acl url_static       path_beg       -i /static /images /javascript /stylesheets
    acl url_static       path_end       -i .jpg .gif .png .css .js .svg .html
    acl health_check     path_beg   -i /isAlive

    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }  ! health_check 
    mode http
    #reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    use_backend static          if url_static
    default_backend             app

frontend dal
bind *:8080  ssl crt /etc/haproxy/ssl/a/real.pem
default_backend dal 


#frontend  peerlist
#    bind *:32769

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# peer listen listen
#---------------------------------------------------------------------




#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# statistics listen
#---------------------------------------------------------------------

    listen stats :9000 #Listen on localhost port 9000
    mode http
    stats enable #Enable statistics
    stats hide-version #Hide HAPRoxy version, a necessity for any public-facing site
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics #Show this text in authentication popup (escape space characters with backslash)
    stats uri /haproxy_stats #The URI of the stats page, in this case localhost:9000/haproxy_stats
    stats auth Username:Password #Set a username and password

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# static backend for serving up images, stylesheets and such
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
backend static
    balance     roundrobin
    #server      static 127.0.0.1:4331 check
    server  app1 app.cooladata.com:443 check ssl verify none
    server  app2 app.cooladata.com:443 check ssl verify none

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# round robin balancing between the various backends
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
backend app
    #mode tcp
    balance     roundrobin
    option httpchk GET /isAlive
    http-check expect string true
    #cookie SRVNAME insert
    #appsession SRVNAME len 64 timeout 30 request-learn
    #appsession SRVNAME len 64 timeout 30 
    #server  app1 <ip>:80  cookie S1 check
    #server  app2 <ip>:80  cookie S2 check

    stick-table type string len 64 size 100k peers mypeers 
    stick on req.cook(JSESSIONID)
    stick store-response res.cook(JSESSIONID)
    server  app1 <be1-ip>:443   check ssl verify none
    server  app2 <be2-ip>:443   check ssl verify none
    #server  app3 127.0.0.1:5003 check
    #server  app4 127.0.0.1:5004 check

backend dal
    balance     roundrobin
    option httpchk GET /health
    http-check expect string Ok
    server  dm1 <be-ip>:<port> check   inter 2000
    server  dm2 <be2-ip>:<port>   check   inter 2000
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a setup problem, nothing was inherently wrong with the sample configuration file.

Comment: why is the peer listener commented out? I am asking because I am confused with the peer ports. Where do they come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried running on centos 6, and everything worked like a charm.
SElinux was the problem, not really sure why yet.